# Is there a fast way to check if all attributes inside an initialized struct are uninitialized?

Tags: c, struct

Consider the following struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int id;
    int *key;
    char *message;
    char ret;
} some_type;
```

and inside my code I have now:

```
some_type *a = (some_type *) malloc(sizeof(some_type));
```

I initialized the struct but not its attributes yet. Is there a simple way to retrieve that kind of information? I want a function which gives me true if all attributes of an initialized struct are uninitialized.

**EDIT:** I am doing this because I want to realize a specific functionality in a `getopt` in my program. Arguments that are passed over command line by the user are collected in this struct. If no arguments except an "-h" is passed, I want to print out a help section. Thus, I thought I could use such a function to check if nothing else is initialized inside my struct. If this is not possible, can somebody else think of a short way to achieve my target?

Comment: The short answer is "no". The long answer is "Unfortunately not"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we're going to have some repetition of types, so remove the gratuitous and actively harmful one:

```
some_type *a = (some_type *) malloc(sizeof(some_type));
```

becomes:

```
some_type *a = malloc(sizeof *a);
```

Now, there's no way to "probe" whether particular/all members are initialized, but you can at least ensure that everything not explicitly initialized gets a default initializeation, by assigning an initialized struct to yours:

```
*a = (some_type){ .id = x, .key = y }; // message and ret have default initializers
```

This isn't quite as good as what you wanted, but better than nothing.

If you don't just want to help catch mistaken use of uninitialized data, but actually have a long-term need to know validity status, then dbush's answer is for you. You need either a separate member indicating validity flags for the optional members, or you need sentinel values (like null pointers, negative integers, etc.) which you will interpret as "lacking any value", and you need to set them up (which requires doing each individually, whereas a boolean flag could work with my default-initializer approach above).

Comment: couldn't I use an enum instead of a struct for my particular getopt-problem and iterate through it? Or is there something, I am missing?

Comment: @Lavair: For the XY problem, which really should be an entirely separate question, just have a flag that starts at 0 and set it to 1 every time you process an option.

Answer (score 4):

I was using CRC for every data structure when I was programming uCs working in the radioactive environment. Use calloc, add CRC and probability that data is wrong will be minimized

## edit

```
struct data {
    uint8_t a;
};

typedef struct
{
    struct data d;
    uint8_t _padding[4 * (sizeof(struct data) & 3) - (sizeof(struct data) & 3)];
    uint32_t CRC;
} __attribute__((packed)) data1;
```

Comment: Curious: 8, 16 or 32 bit CRC?

Comment: 32 bit hardware  - STM32 uCs

Comment: *using CRC for every data structures* How did you account for structure padding?

Answer (score 1):

In general, there's no way to know whether a variable is initialized or not.  For memory returned by `malloc`, all memory is uninitialized.

You need some way of keeping track of that yourself, either by assigning some known default values or separate flag variables.

Regarding command line arguments passed to your program, each of them should have a default value.  Then if particular arguments contain the default value then you can display your help message.

Comment: Is this approach with the default value common? Because I could equivalently check for every single arg if it is uninitialized and just use a big if condition which checks for each arg if all is uninitialized. But I would prefer a dynamic approach where I don't have to change at multiple ends each time I change argument functionalities.

Comment: @Lavair Instead of printing help if only -h is specified, just don't bother checking the other arguments if -h is specified and exit after printing the help message.  That's what most command line utilities do.